# Delete chrome cache programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

I am trying to delete Chrome browser cache on logout of an application. I am using below set of code inside logout button click event and it doesn't clear browser cache.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

I also have placed the below meta tags in cshtml page and didn't help. Really appreciate any suggestions.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you could clarify why you need to do that. Because I don't think this is even possible, at least using headers you're trying to set. What those headers do is telling the browser (or some intermediate agents) if it should cache this particular response for the request. You can't affect saved versions of other responses of other web applications. By the way, it seems that all of these calls: `SetRevalidation`, `SetCacheability`, `SetNoStore` set the same HTTP header - `cache-control`

Answer (score 0):

You can also add with yours this lines and check it again.

```
HttpContext.Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
HttpContext.Response.Expires = 0;
HttpContext.Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

I also suggest to increase  `DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)` from -1 day to -1 year at least.

Comment: Should I add these lines along with the existing codes or the three lines of code alone suffice?

Comment: @Ryan Together with yours.

Comment: @Ryan What do you mean "delete" ? Did he ask again for the page or not ? Do you see the previous data on page or not ?

Comment: I can see the cached images and file still there in the browser and they aren't deleted.

Comment: @Ryan How you see them ? with some special program ? Anyway - you can not delete the images from browser - you can only clear the cache, and browser re-read them - maybe if you make some kind of trick to have the same image two times, on normal, and one blank, and just load the blank when you want to delete it.

Comment: @Ryan Other alternative is to make an ashx handler and send the images using this handler. But there are no command to delete them from browser - there are only commands to say to the browser to remove it from cache and read it again - or maybe other commands to say to the browser to not store it on cache (but he store it anyway)